# If $ \log_{12} 18 = a$, then what is $\log_{24} 16$ equal to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I was trying to revert the logarithm into indices, but couldn't do it.

There are four options in the answer:

1. $\frac{8-4a}{(5-a)}$
2. $\frac{1}{3+a}$
3. $\frac{4a-1}{2+3a}$
4. $\frac{8-4a}{5+a}$

Comment: Please get the powers right. Is it $2^{18}$ and $4^{16}$ in the question? What comes underneath the logarithm in the first expression?

Comment: actually i'm having prob with mathjax. the bases are 12 and 24 . and the powers are 18 and 16. can you please edit it .

Comment: If you are having problems with MathJax I suggest that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
as a quick reference for future posts. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution
$$\frac{\log_218}{\log_212}=a$$
$$\frac{2\log_23+1}{\log_23+2}=a$$
which gives
$\log_23=\frac{1-2a}{a-2}=\frac{-(1-2a)}{-(a-2)}=\frac{2a-1}{2-a}$
Second is
$$\frac{\log_216}{\log_224}$$
$$\frac{4}{\log_23+3}$$
Substitute for $\log_23$ giving......
$$\frac{8-4a}{5-a}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\log_32=x$.

Hence, $a=\log_{12}18=\frac{x+2}{1+2x}$, which gives $x=\frac{a-2}{1-2a}$.

Hence, $\log_{24}16=\frac{4x}{3x+1}=\frac{\frac{4(a-2)}{1-2a}}{\frac{3(a-2}{1-2a}+1}=\frac{4(a-2)}{a-5}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the base-change formula, we can write this as:

$\large\frac{log 18}{log 12} = a \\[0.4cm]
\large\frac{2log 3+log 2}{log 3+2log 2}=a\\[0.4cm]
2 log 3 + log 2=a log 3+2alog2\\
(2-a)log3=(2a-1)log2\\[0.4cm]
log 3=\frac{(2a-1)log2}{2-a} ......     (1)\\[0.4cm]
log_{24}16 = \frac{log24}{log16}\\[0.4cm]
\Rightarrow \frac{4log2}{log3+3log2}\\[0.4cm]
Now, substituting \text{ } value \text{ } of \text{ } log3: \\
\frac{4log2}{\frac{(2a-1)log2}{2-a}+2log2} = \frac{4(2-a)}{5-a} = \frac{8-4a}{5-a} \text{ } (Ans.)$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

We are given that $ \ \log_{12} 18 \ = \ a \ \   $ or $ \ 12^a \  = \  \ 18  \ \   $  and wish to find $ \ p \ $ such that $ \ 24^p \ = \  16 \ \ \ . \ $  Starting from the first equation, we have
$$ ( \ 2^2·3 \ )^a  \   = \  \ 2 · 3^2 \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \  2^{2a \ - \ 1}   \   = \  \  3^{2 \ - \ a}  \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ 2^{(2a \ - \ 1)/( 2 \ - \ a)}   \ \   = \ \ 3 \ \ . $$

Now that we have a way of "eliminating" factors of $ \ 3 \ \ , \ $ we can insert this into the second equation to obtain $ \ p \ \ : $
$$ ( \ 2^3 · 3 \ )^p \ = \  2^4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2^{3p} \ · \ [ \ 2^{(2a \ - \ 1)/( 2 \ - \ a)}  \ ]^{ \ p} \ \ = \ \ 2^4 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 3p \ + \ \frac{p·(2a \ - \ 1)}{ 2 \ - \ a} \ \ = \ \ 4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 3p·(2 \ - \ a) \ + \ p·(2a \ - \ 1) \ \ = \ \ 4·(2 \ - \ a)  $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ p \ \ = \ \ \frac{4·(2 \ - \ a)}{3 ·(2 \ - \ a) \ + \  (2a \ - \ 1)}  \ \ = \ \ \frac{4·(2 \ - \ a)}{6 \ - \ 3a  \ + \   2a \ - \ 1 } \ \ = \ \ \frac{4·(2 \ - \ a)}{5 \ - \ a   } \ \ , $$
which is choice $ \ \mathbf{(1)} \ \ . $

As a check, $ \ a \ \approx \ 1.1632 \ \Rightarrow \ p \ \approx \ \frac{4·(2 \ - \ 1.1632)}{5 \ - \ 1.1632   } \ \approx \ 0.8724 \ \ , \ $ which *does* yield $ \ 24^{0.8724} \ \approx \ 16 \ \ . $

[I've tried some experimentation to see whether if it helpful to manipulate the first equation to produce a factor of $ \ 16 \ $ which could then be replaced by $ \ 24^p \ \ , \ $ but it proves to be better to find a way to "dispose" of the factors of $ \ 2 \ $ or of $ \ 3 \ $ early on.]